# What may make non-optimized F# code faster than optimized code?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, f#

So I've decided to give F# a try and ported one the algorithms I've written in C# to it. At one point, I have noticed that debug build run faster than the release one. I then played with the optimization settings and got these results:

The times show the total execution time of the algorithm over 100000 runs. I am using the F# compiler that comes with Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Target platform is Any CPU.

```
Opt off, tail calls off: 5.81s
Opt off, tail calls on : 5.79s
Opt on , tail calls off: 6.48s
Opt on , tail calls on : 6.40s
```

I am really puzzled by this - why does the optimization make the code run slower? The C# version of the algorithm does not exhibit this behavior (altho it is implemented in a slightly different way)

Here is a stripped down version of the F# code, it is an algorithm that finds patterns in molecules. All the code that this F# program relies on is written in F#.

```
namespace Motives
  module Internal = 
    type Motive = 
      { ResidueSet: Set<Residue>; AtomSet: Set<IAtom> }
      member this.Atoms : IAtom seq = 
        seq { 
          for r in this.ResidueSet do yield! r.Atoms
          yield! this.AtomSet
        }
      static member fromResidues (residues : Residue seq) = residues |> Seq.fold (fun (m: Set<Residue>) r -> m.Add(r)) Set.empty |> fun rs -> { ResidueSet = rs; AtomSet = Set.empty }
      static member fromAtoms (atoms : IAtom seq) = atoms |> Seq.fold (fun (m: Set<IAtom>) a -> m.Add(a)) Set.empty |>  fun atoms -> { ResidueSet = Set.empty; AtomSet = atoms }
      static member merge (m1: Motive) (m2: Motive) = { ResidueSet = Set.union m1.ResidueSet m2.ResidueSet; AtomSet = Set.union m1.AtomSet m2.AtomSet }
      static member distance (m1: Motive) (m2: Motive) = Seq.min (seq { for a in m1.Atoms do for b in m2.Atoms -> a.Position.DistanceTo(b.Position) })

    type Structure with 
      static member fromMotive (m: Motive) (parent: IStructure) (addBonds: bool) : IStructure = 
        let atoms = AtomCollection.FromUniqueAtoms(m.Atoms)
        let bonds = 
          match addBonds with 
          | true -> BondCollection.Create(atoms |> Seq.map (fun a -> parent.Bonds.[a]) |> Seq.concat)
          | _ -> BondCollection.Empty
        Structure.Create (parent.Id + "_" + atoms.[0].Id.ToString(), atoms, bonds)

    // KDTree used for range queries
    // AminoChains used for regex queries
    type StructureContext = 
      { Structure: IStructure; KDTree: Lazy<KDAtomTree>; AminoChains: Lazy<(Residue array * string) list> }
      static member create (structure: IStructure) =
        match structure.IsPdbStructure() with
        | false -> { Structure = structure; KDTree = Lazy.Create(fun () -> structure.Atoms.ToKDTree()); AminoChains = Lazy.CreateFromValue([]) }
        | true  -> 
          let aminoChains = new System.Func<(Residue array * string) list> (fun () ->
            let residues = structure.PdbResidues() |> Seq.filter (fun r -> r.IsAmino)
            residues
            |> Seq.groupBy (fun r -> r.ChainIdentifier)
            |> Seq.map (fun (k,rs) -> rs |> Array.ofSeq, String.concat "" (rs |> Seq.map (fun r -> r.ShortName)))
            |> List.ofSeq)
          { Structure = structure; KDTree = Lazy.Create(fun () -> structure.Atoms.ToKDTree()); AminoChains = Lazy.Create(aminoChains) }

    // Remember the named motives from named patterns
    type MatchContext = 
      { StructureContext: StructureContext; NamedMotives: Map<string, Motive> }
      static member merge (c1: MatchContext) (c2: MatchContext) = 
        { StructureContext = c1.StructureContext; NamedMotives = c2.NamedMotives |> Map.fold (fun m k v -> m.Add(k,v)) c1.NamedMotives }

    type MatchedMotive = Motive * MatchContext 

    type Pattern = 
      | EmptyPattern
      | GeneratingPattern of ( StructureContext -> MatchedMotive seq )
      | ConstraintPattern of ( MatchedMotive -> MatchedMotive option ) * Pattern
      static member matches (p: Pattern) (context: StructureContext) : MatchedMotive seq = 
        match p with  
        | GeneratingPattern generator -> generator context
        | ConstraintPattern (transform, pattern) ->
          Pattern.matches pattern context
          |> Seq.choose (fun m -> transform m)
        | _ -> Seq.empty

    let ringPattern (names: string list) =
      let fingerprint = 
        names 
        |> Seq.map (fun s -> ElementSymbol.Create(s).ToString()) 
        |> Seq.sort
        |> String.concat ""  
      let generator (context: StructureContext) =
        let rings = context.Structure.Rings().GetRingsByFingerprint(fingerprint)
        rings |> Seq.map (fun r -> Motive.fromAtoms r.Atoms, { StructureContext = context; NamedMotives = Map.empty })
      GeneratingPattern generator

  open Internal

  type MotiveFinder (pattern: string) =
    // I am using a hard coded pattern here for testing purposes
    let pattern = ringPattern ["C"; "C"; "C"; "C"; "C"; "O"]
    member this.Matches (structure: IStructure) =
      Pattern.matches pattern (StructureContext.create structure)
      |> Seq.map (fun (m, mc) -> Structure.fromMotive m mc.StructureContext.Structure false) 
      |> List.ofSeq 
      |> List.sortBy (fun s -> s.Atoms.[0].Id)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// performance test

let warmUp = (new MotiveFinder("")).Matches (StructureReader.ReadPdb(filename, computeBonds = true))
printfn "%i" (List.length warmUp)

let structure = StructureReader.ReadPdb(filename, computeBonds = true)
let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
let nruns = 100000
let result = 
  seq { 
    for i in 1 .. nruns do
      yield (new MotiveFinder("")).Matches structure 
  } |> Seq.nth (nruns-1)

stopWatch.Stop()
printfn "Time elapsed: %f seconds" stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
```

**EDIT2:**

I seem to have narrowed down the problem to the implementation of the Set type.

For this code:

```
let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
let runs = 1000000
let result = 
  seq {
    for i in 1 .. runs do
      let setA = [ 1 .. (i % 10) + 5 ] |> Set.ofList
      let setB = [ 1 .. (i % 10) + 5 ] |> Set.ofList
      yield Set.union setA setB
  } |> Seq.nth (runs - 1)

stopWatch.Stop()
printfn "Time elapsed: %f seconds" stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
printfn "%A" result
```

I get ~7.5s with optimization off and ~8.0s with optimization on. Still target = Any CPU (and I have i7-860 processor).

**EDIT3:** 
And right after I posted the previous edit I figured I should try it on lists only.

So for

```
let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
let runs = 1000000
let result1 = 
  seq {
    for i in 1 .. runs do
      let list = [ 1 .. i % 100 + 5 ]
      yield list
  } |> Seq.nth (runs - 1)

stopWatch.Stop()
printfn "Time elapsed: %f seconds" stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
printfn "%A" result1
```

I get ~3s with opt. off and ~3.5s with opt. on.

**EDIT4:**

If I remove the seq builder and just do

```
let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
let runs = 1000000
let mutable ret : int list = []
for i in 1 .. runs do
  let list = [ 1 .. i % 100 + 5 ]
  ret <- list

stopWatch1.Stop()
printfn "Time elapsed: %f seconds" stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
printfn "%A" ret
```

I get ~3s with optimization both on and off. So it seem that the problem is somewhere in optimizing the seq builder code.

Strangely enough, I wrote a test app in C#:

```cs
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

int runs = 1000000;

var result = Enumerable.Range(1, runs)
  .Select(i => Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule.OfSeq(Enumerable.Range(1, i % 100 + 5)))
  .ElementAt(runs - 1);

watch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}s", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

And the code happens to run almost twice as fast as the F# solution at ~1.7s.

**EDIT5:**

Based on the discussion with Jon Harrop I have found out the thing that is causing the optimized code run slower (I still don't know why tho).

If I change `Motive.Atoms` from

```
member this.Atoms : IAtom seq = 
  seq { 
    for r in this.ResidueSet do yield! r.Atoms
      yield! this.AtomSet
  }
```

to

```
member this.Atoms : IAtom seq = 
  Seq.append (this.ResidueSet |> Seq.collect (fun r -> r.Atoms)) this.AtomSet
```

then the program runs ~7.1s in both optimized and non-optimized version. Which is slower than the `seq` version, but at least consistent.

So it seems that the F# compiler just can't optimize computation expressions and actually makes them slower by trying so.

Comment: Looks like the compiler simply fails at optimizing that specific algorithm.

Comment: @Niklas: Well, yeah. But there has to be a reason for that and I wonder what it is...

Comment: Impossible to say anything without working code. Your `Residue` and `IAtom` types are undefined. Your `Structure` type definition doesn't even seem to be valid F# code. Can you provide a working example?

Comment: @JonHarrop Uploaded a (hopefully) working sulution to http://www.filefactory.com/file/c08bd93/n/FinderSharp.zip To clarify the IAtom etc types - these come from a library I am working on.

Comment: `IStructure`, `AtomCollection`, `BondCollection` and `KDAtomTree` are undefined...

Comment: @JonHarrop Try re-adding the WebChemistry.Framework.Core.dll as a reference from the Lib folder (maybe it will be required to add the Rx libraries as well).

Comment: @Dave: Would really help if you could post the entire source code rather than just wrapper code and a DLL.

Comment: @JonHarrop: The wrapper DLL is several thousands lines of code which I eventually plan to make open source, but I am not quite ready to do that yet. Also I am very positive that the C# code from the DLL wrapper does not cause the slowdown (see EDIT5).

Answer (score 6):

I can also observe your wrapper code and penultimate example running slightly slower with optimizations enabled but the difference is less than 10% and, although anomalous, I am not surprised that optimizations can sometimes slightly degrade performance.

I should note that your style of coding leaves a lot of room for optimization but without the entire source code it is not possible for me to help optimize it. Your example uses the following code:

```
let result1 =
  seq {
    for i in 1 .. runs do
      let list = [ 1 .. i % 100 + 5 ]
      yield list
  } |> Seq.nth (runs - 1)
```

when this is shorter, more idiomatic and orders of magnitude faster:

```
let result1 =
  Seq.init runs (fun i -> List.init ((i+1) % 100 + 5) ((+) 1))
  |> Seq.nth (runs - 1)
```

**EDIT**

In your comments below you say that you want to execute the function argument in which case I would not assume that `Seq.nth` will do this for you so I would use a `for` loop instead:

```
let mutable list = []
for i=1 to runs do
  list <- List.init (i % 100 + 5) ((+) 1)
list
```

This is still 9× faster than the original.

Comment: I understand about the coding style, I am fairly new to F#. I was just surprised the optimizer made code as simple as in the example actually slower as apposed to running at least as fast as the not optimized version.

Comment: Also it seems that `Seq.init f |> Seq.nth i` only actually executes the function `f` once. And that's not really the behavior I want...

Comment: As an example of my prev. comment: `let t = ref 0;
let x = Seq.init 1000 (fun i -> t := !t + i; !t) |> Seq.nth 999;
printfn "%A %A" !t x` prints 999 999. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok I get you can optimize this particular statement.   But I think we've got a little side tracked here. My original question was why does the optimizer make the code run slower.

Comment: Yes. I don't know why the F# optimizer degrades performance slightly in this case. I do know that the F# implementation of seq is decidedly suboptimal and that the C# implementation is much more efficient. As I said, I am not surprised that optimizations can sometimes slightly degrade performance. What results do you get if you compile the entire source code as either Debug or Release (as opposed to just the wrapper and the DLL as, I assume, Release)?

Comment: If I reference the debug version of the DLL, the difference between the optimized and nonoptimized versions is 6.2s (opt off) vs 7s (opt on). Anyway, I have found what's causing the slowdown (as it is pretty much the only thing that gets called repeatedly as IStructure.Rings() is cached). I did this F# program as a small experiment/wanted to learn F# and in doing so I found this unexpected behavior in even such simple code so I figured I would as why is that..